# Is this a valid proof by induction?

Tags: calculus

I am working on comparison tests for infinite series.

Does $\sum\limits_{n\ge1}\frac{n!}{n^n}$ converge?

Undoubtedly there are easier ways to test this, but I embarked on this method and now find myself subsequently curious as to if this makes logical sense.

Observing $n^n$ grows like a beast, and faster than $n!$, I went with comparing $\frac{n!}{n^n}$ with $\frac{1}{n^2}$.
Explicitly the statement: $\frac{n!}{n^n} < \frac{1}{n^2}$

I did not know how to go about this after playing around with rewriting the expression and what not...I could not simplify although I surely believe a method(s) exist.

So I decided to try a proof by induction....which I have not done in a while and needed a refresher. 
$$\frac{n!}{n^n} < \frac{1}{n^2}$$
$n! < n^{n-2}$  for $n > N$, tried $N=3$...false, plugged in $10$ and found a true statement. Base case is $N=10$. 
I assume $n! < n^{n-2}$

So now trying to show that this is true for $n+1$, $n! < n^{n-2}$ ----> plugged in $n+1$ for $n$,

$$\begin{align*}(n+1)! &< (n+1)^{n-1}\\
(n+1)*n! &< (n+1)^{n-1}\end{align*}$$
Using my assumption this means: $(n+1)* n^{n-2} < (n+1)^{n-1}$
Therefore,

$n^{n-2} < (n+1)^{n-2}$; a true statement for my defined values of $n$.

So by comparison with $\frac{1}{n^2}$ the series $\sum\limits_{n\ge1} \frac{n!}{n^n}$ converges.

Comment: (n+1)! < (n+1)^(n-1) -> (n+1)*n! < (n+1)^(n-1)

Comment: It is not difficult to show that $$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k!}{k^k}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(1+x\log(x))^2}.$$ The irrationality of such a constant has been the subject of a recent question on MSE. Unfortunately, I am not able to find it at the moment.

Comment: In any case, the absolute convergence just follows from the well-known inequality $k!\leq \frac{k^{k+1}}{e^k}$.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your inductive step is hard to parse. You *assume* $n!<n^{n-2}$ and you *want to show* $(n+1)!<(n+1)^{n-1}$. When you start deductions with the equation you are trying to prove, it is difficult to tell whether or not the reasoning is circular.

Instead, let's start with the lefthand side of the inequality you want and try to get to the righthand side using just the inductive hypothesis:
\begin{align*}
(n+1)!&=(n+1)n!&\\
&<(n+1)n^{n-2}&\mbox{(inductive hypothesis)}\\
&<(n+1)(n+1)^{n-2}&(n^{n-2}<(n+1)^{n-2})\\
&=(n+1)^{n-1}
\end{align*}

Comment: Sorry if this is so trivial that it is blatantly obvious but did the inductive hypothesis just come from defining it such that it works to show that the left hand side is indeed less than the right hand side?

Comment: Everything else I am able to follow easily enough

Comment: @taunotpi You verified that the inductive hypothesis holds when $n=10$. The argument above shows that it therefore holds for $n+1=11$ (which in turn shows that it holds for $(n+1)+1=12$, etc...).